# Creating your own HRESULT?

Tags: c++, com, hresult

I already have a project that uses a lot of COM, and HRESULTS. Anyways I was wondering if it's possible to define your own HRESULT, AND be able to use the FormatMessage() for our own HRESULT?

I dug around and can't find anything. Any ideas?

EDIT

Basically I want to define a set of my own HRESULTs instead of just returning E_FAIL. Or one of the other generic ones. Like E_FAIL is fine. But let's say I want to point out that for example the Geoprocessing subsystem crashed or the file is an invalid Raster Image. The application already uses COM throughout it.

Comment: That's what the `lpSource` argument is for in the [`FormatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage) call. You'll want to pass the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` flag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes of course. Typically you create a [.mc file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996906%28VS.85%29.aspx) and include that in your project. Instruct the [mc compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385638%28VS.85%29.aspx) to build it - this creates a header file and a .rc file. The HRESULTS are defined in the header file. You include the .rc file in your project as normal for the resource compiler to compile - this puts the message definitions into your final module. Then you can use the normal [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions to format the messages using the HRESULTS and generate error info and the other stuff.

I have this as the command line for one of my .mc files:

```
mc   -h "../include" -r "../include" "..\include\errors.mc"
```

This creates errors.rc and errors.h in the include directory. Then I did:

```
#include "errors.rc"
```

in my main .rc file for the project.

The .mc file looks a bit like this:

```
LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)

MessageId=0x1
SymbolicName=SOME_CATEGORY
Language=English
Some Category
.

MessageID=
Severity=Error
SymbolicName=ERROR_INVALID_PROP_INDEX

Language=English
Invalid property index %1
.
```

with lots of error numbers defined.