# What's the rule on hijacking Windows error codes for return from my own code?

Tags: winapi

Are the error codes defined in `WinError.h` free to be hijacked and returned my by own code?

There are some *generic* **Win32** error codes defined:

- `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`: *"The system cannot find the file specified."*

that of course i could use for my own purpose when a file is not found.

Then there are still some generic errors:

- `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`: *"Access is denied."*

but it's generally understood that this error comes when trying to access a file. i might have an `HttpGet()` function that returns `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the server returns a `401`.

But then there are codes that are defined as being for a particular purpose. Imagine my `HttpGet()` function throws an error if the `https` certificate is not a type we support:

- `ERROR_IPSEC_IKE_INVALID_CERT_TYPE`: *"Invalid certificate type"*

except that code is defined quite clearly in `WinError.h` as belonging to IPSec:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                               //
//           Start of IPSec Error codes          //
//                                               //
//                 13000 to 13999                //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

...

//
// MessageId: ERROR_IPSEC_IKE_INVALID_CERT_TYPE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Invalid certificate type
//
#define ERROR_IPSEC_IKE_INVALID_CERT_TYPE 13819L
```

But the error text is exactly what i want!

We have a financial system that requires a 2nd user to approve a transaction; this means that the entered credentials must be a different user than the first person:

- `MK_E_MUSTBOTHERUSER`: *"User input required for operation to succeed"*

or perhaps:

- `ERROR_LOGON_TYPE_NOT_GRANTED`: *"Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."*

i get the sense that spelunking through WinError, cherry-picking error codes by the *string* they show and re-purposing them to indicate errors they were not designed for, is something [Raymond](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) would give me a slap for.

Are Windows error codes a freely available "pool" of error codes? Or are all Windows error codes only to be returned from Microsoft's code?

If i'm creating `HRESULTS`, i need to use *some* code. And it would be great if the user could call [`FormatMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to turn my `HRESULT` into a string. (Especially since my return HRESULT could either me either my own code, or an HRESULT that was returned to me from Microsoft code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i may have found my own answer, by actually [*reading the documentation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ### [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> The System Error Codes are very broad. *...*  Because these codes are defined in WinError.h for anyone to use, sometimes the codes are returned by non-system software.

Although only *error **codes*** are described as such (i.e. positive numbers from 0-15999).

But the same spirit starts to apply to COM error codes:

- `E_NOTIMPL`: 0x80004001 *Not implemented*
- `E_INVALIDARG`: 0x80070057 *One or more arguments are invalid*
- `E_FAIL`: 0x80004005 *Unspecified error*  (*The dreaded 80004005 unspecified error, error*)

In fact it's [Delphi's `safecall` mapping](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComObj.HandleSafeCallException) that converts any generic exception into

- `E_UNEXPECTED` 0x8000FFFF *Catastrophic failure*

So it's quite expected to use Microsoft's HRESULT codes.

---

You also have the HRESULTs that are [HRESULT formulations of the standard Win32 error codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/03/942851.aspx), e.g. [`E_HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a wrapper around [`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (6):

```
E_HANDLE = 0x80070006;   //Invalid handle
```

Which is done using the HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 macro.

Although it might be morally questionable to use Microsoft HRESULTS outside [generic facilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- `FACILITY_NULL` For broadly applicable common status codes such as S_OK.
- `FACILITY_RPC` For status codes returned from remote procedure calls.
- `FACILITY_DISPATCH` For late-binding IDispatch interface errors.
- `FACILITY_ITF` For most status codes returned from interface methods. The actual meaning of the error is defined by the interface. That is, two HRESULTs with exactly the same 32-bit value returned from two different interfaces might have different meanings.
- `FACILITY_WIN32` Used to provide a means of handling error codes from functions in the Windows API as an HRESULT.

Comment: I read that more as a realization than an endorsement.  However, everybody does it so it's probably "safe".

Answer (score 4):

When you define your own `HRESULT` codes, you are recommended to use [`FACILITY_ITF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and define your codes in this range of application-defined codes. Yes the codes would overlap between applications, but you can also provide additional descriptive message through `SetErrorInfo` API and indicating support by implementing `ISupportErrorInfo` if you are implementing COM object/interface.

An excerpt from `COM+ Programming` book explains this in greater detail: [COM+ programming: a practical guide using Visual C++ and ATL](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jPXGR1NSsckC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=define+your+own+HRESULT+FACILITY_ITF&source=bl&ots=2oR_OzvQfD&sig=3Sn7EHoxpjV6Or1IK6KXxdItbyw&hl=uk&sa=X&ei=GaNjT4y_NIHE4gS53PihCA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20your%20own%20HRESULT%20FACILITY_ITF&f=false) (page 67).

Simpler than that, you can use your custom facility code and this might be different in different modules, so you can easily identify which module is the source of the problem.

If you put `MESSAGETABLE` resource into your binary, `FormatMessage` API could resolve HRESULTs and extract description text for individual codes, just like it happens with regular Windows error codes (the app would still need to provide module handle to the API function).

See also: [Creating your own HRESULT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522853/creating-your-own-hresult)

---

**O.P. Edit:**

From Microsoft's [Open Protocol Specification of HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)s

> ### 2.1 HRESULT
>
> The HRESULT numbering space is vendor-extensible. Vendors can supply their own values for this field, as long as the **C** bit (0x20000000) is set, indicating it is a customer code.
>
> **C (1 bit)**: Customer. This bit specifies if the value is customer-defined or Microsoft-defined. The bit is set for customer-defined values and clear for Microsoft-defined values. [<1>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1714a7aa-8e53-4076-8f8d-75073b780a41(v=prot.10)#id1)
>
> [<1> Section 2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a%28v=prot.10%29#endNote1): All [HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b93995d-dee9-44cd-83c1-d2ccbd69bc29%28v=prot.10%29#hresult) values used by Microsoft have the **C** bit clear.

This means that i can make up any HRESULT i like as long as i set the **C** bit. As a practical matter this means that i can any any *code* i like, e.g.:

```
E_LOGON_FAILURE = 0xA007052E;
```

Of course i didn't come up with this number at random.

First i set the high bit to 1, to indicate an error:

```
0x80000000
```

Then i "choose" an error code, e.g. [1326 (0x52E hex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
0x8000052E
```

Then i need to choose a facility. Let's chooooose, on i dunno, [seven](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198%28v=prot.10%29.aspx):

```
0x8007052E
```

Finally i set [the **Customer** bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198%28v=prot.10%29.aspx), to indicate it is not a Microsoft defined HRESULT:

```
0xA007052E
```

And coincidentally everything up until the last step is the guts of the Microsoft [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro:

> Maps a system error code to an HRESULT value.
>
> ```
>  HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(DWORD x);
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Don't go down this road, and just define your own.

**Reuse of the codes themselves** is pointless, since having your own codes is just one `#define` away.

**Reuse of the error strings** is not such a good idea either:

- These will be localized. So if your (English) application runs on a Chinese version of Windows, the user will see a mixture of the two languages.
- Microsoft might change the text at their whim, with a new release of Windows or with an update. For example, if you used `ERROR_IPSEC_IKE_INVALID_CERT_TYPE` to indicate HTTPS certificate errors, and Microsoft decided to fix their vague message to say "Invalid **IPSEC IKE** certificate type" instead? (I don't know what IKE is at all, and have only a vague notion about IPSEC, but you get the point.)
- You'll have no way of customizing the error messages to be clearer or more specific.
- Once users of your API start using `FormatMessage`, you'll be forever tied to the set of error codes and messages that Microsoft provides.

If you already know that Raymond Chen would slap you, why are you even considering this? ;)

Comment: Because maybe it's exactly the **right** thing to do. Maybe they are there to be used, "The developer went to all this work, but if they just read the documentation they would find all these error codes already defined for them."

Comment: I'm guilty of reusing Windows error codes at times (it is quite tempting), but I totally agree with this.  If you want to prevent collisions with Windows error codes you can use [32-bit values that have bit 29 set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); this is analogous to HRESULTS with the customer bit set.  This also gives you total control over error messages, insertion strings, etc.