# Custom HRESULT from COM component

Tags: c#, c++, com, hresult

Creating custom `HRESULT` has been covered here
[Creating your own HRESULT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522853/creating-your-own-hresult)

Solution to above question is fine for c++ native clients, they can use the returned `HRESULT` to `FormatMessage()` and get error string, what about C# and JavaScript client? For discussion's sake let us forget `FormatMessage()` via PInvoke.

e.g. if a COM function returns `E_ACCESSDENIED` and C# client will receive it via nicely packaged exception, complete with error string and symbolic name(`E_ACCESSDENIED`)

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

It is understood system error codes have been mapped to .Net exceptions.
Questions is how to return an message compiler generated custom error codes packaged in `HRESULT`?

Is `MAKE_HRESULT` the answer?

Comment: Check out and implement the [`IErrorInfo` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, your custom HRESULT values should be in the proper custom HRESULT facility.

Comment: that works like a charm for JavaScript, but C# still doesn't produce pretty messages.

Comment: Sorry, I have no direct experience with this stuff since 15 years ago. Otherwise your description might have triggered some "aha, that's what it's about" recognition circuit. :(

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awy7adbx.aspx says that it _ought_ to work...

Comment: Works fine in C# as well, the CLR always queries for ISupportErrorInfo.  You can see it being done [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/stdinterfaces.cpp).  You must be doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: yes, `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)` was missing so QI must be failing for CLR.