# HRESULT: distinguish custom code from system one

Tags: c++, windows, com, hresult

Similar question [was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522853/creating-your-own-hresult), but i haven't found some answers there.

As i understand, for making custom HRESULT codes i create an `.mc` file where i describe the codes, then compile it and get an `.h` file. But i can't get it how to prevent possible overlapping with the system ones.

Example:

```
LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)
MessageId = 0x0
Severity = Success
Facility = Application
SymbolicName = CUSTOME_CODE
Language=English
Cusome message
.
```

produces

```
#define CUSTOME_CODE                     0x00000000L
```

which is actually the same with `S_OK`.

If i return `CUSTOME_CODE` from my method, a caller can't distinguish it from `S_OK`;

Wiki says HRESULT contains a bit for distinguishing Microsoft / User defined code properties, but i don't understand how to set it. Also MSDN says that the bit is just "reserved".

How do i make code which can't overlap the system ones?

Comment: See [HRESULT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198), the docs for [mc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385638), and the spec for [message text files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996906). For creating an `HRESULT` header, use the `-o` command-line option. To set the customer bit, use the `-c` command-line option. You may want some symbolic names defined at the top, e.g. `SeverityNames=(Success=0 Fail=2)` and  `FacilityNames=(FACILITY_ITF=4)`.

Comment: There's no technical way to distinguish. You're supposed to use FACILITY_ITF like all non-Microsoft developers on the planet, who can define colliding error codes happily, so it's just a plain nonsense. Note that to add to the confusion, there are some Microsoft components that use FACILITY_ITF ...

Comment: @SimonMourier, you can also set the customer bit in the generated codes via `-c`, but really that's non-standard for `HRESULT` codes. It's reserved for `NTSTATUS` codes.

Comment: When working with my own code (if it's not something distributed worldwide, say), I use custom a facility number of mine, one that does not collide with Microsoft ones (like a high number), although I know it's bad :-)

Comment: @eryksun what's the point to set the customer bit if there is the an agreement that custom HRESULTs must use FACILITY_ITF?

Comment: @fogbit, I suggested it to Simon in response to the claim that "there are some Microsoft components that use FACILITY_ITF", though I don't typically see the customer bit set for `HRESULT` values, and winerror.h states that it's reserved for use with kernel `NTSTATUS` values. Really I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @ery The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) seems to explicitly allow setting the customer bit for `HRESULT` values (at least all the way back to 2013). It doesn't appear to be reserved to `NTSTATUS` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HRESULT, which describes an interface-specific return code, should contain the `FACILTY_ITF` facility code. Note however that return values between 0x0000 and 0x01FF are reserved for COM-defined `FACILITY_ITF` codes.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679751(v=vs.85).aspx) link for further details.

Comment: Also there is an internal structure to the HRESULT.  (Wikipedia) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT and (MSDN) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088(v=vs.85).aspx